# Dynamic (Ajax) share buttons (Facebook, Google+ and Twitter) to share an image, with a link and a description

Tags: ajax, facebook, twitter, share, google-plus

It's been few days I'm looking for a solution and I can't figure out why it's still not working.

**Here is my goal**:
I have a website with a sideshow. The images are dynamically changed (with previous and next buttons). I just want to share an image on social networks (facebook, google+ and twitter) and actually see the image in my wall with a little description and the link to a page.

**Precision**:
The image is a thumbnail (so, not the same url) of the main image and the link I want to publish is neither the page I'm on (which is static due to Ajax) nor the image one.

**My tries**:
I have almost got it on facebook but the image loading failed and it was with a share button (which seems to be deprecated in favor of like) and for google+, the +1 button become red after I click it... I tried XFBML and OpenGraph, but the problem is with Ajax (url is the one of the page or is not changed even with createElement("

**Questions**:
1. Is there any packaged solution (like addthis, but working the way I want)?
2. Or do you have one (or a clue) for me please?
3. Am I the only one to think that offical facebook and google+ ajax documentation are lame?

Thanks a lot.
Hugo

**PS**: if I could have a fly-out to edit a comment with the content I'm about to share, it would be fantastic!

Comment: for the Google +1 button you can probably use the JavaScript APIs (https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#jsapi) to accomplish this. 

You can't pass the shared contents in via JavaScript, though. The image to be shared and your description must exist on a page with a unique URL. You can then mark up this page with opengraph or schema.org markup and use it as the +1. 

Does a unique URL exist which shows the image and desired description?

Comment: This would be a lot of energy to answer in one question as the API's for posting and sharing are all very different between the three networks. Twitter just released an image API but the method for posting is completely different then on FB for example requiring a different answer and possibly different technologies to complete. You can get away with JS or HTTP request sharing for one and may need to send a POST through PHP for another. I suggest splitting up the question per network. Plus I've seen this exact question before, I'll link to it if I can find it.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?  I am in the same boat.

Comment: I guess, for Facebook, you good do that with the iFrame version of the Like button and load dynamically the new iFrame.
Otherwise, you could also use the FBML but re-parse the fb:like with the JavaScript method FB.XFBML.parse.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is with cloaking.

Setup a page which provides the image, title, and description to the social application (aka. facebook, google+). You can then use Javascript to redirect the user to the page you actually want the user to see. For users without Javascript the page should display a link to the target page with a "Click here if you are not automatically redirected". The image should exist on the page but you can place it in a div with style="display: none;" so the user doesn't actually see it.

A more advanced technique would be to use the IP address and browser name (user agent) to determine if the visitor is a user or a social network robot and using a 502 temporary redirect to the page you want the user to see if the visitor is not a social robot.  The social robots would be shown a page which has the image, title and description.

Answer (score 0):

The social sharing buttons that you're using all have one thing in common: they all work best when there's a URL representation for the object that you're sharing. Some of them, namely Facebook's like button and Google's +1 button, use the contents of that page to create the snippet that's shared.

This isn't a new problem, though. This is the same problem faced with [search indexing of AJAX applications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/). Sadly there's no easy solution. Here are a couple of challenging ones:

**Programmatic Solution**
You can improve your back end so that it's capable of rendering pages for each shareable step in the state of your slide show: one page per image. As you step through the slide show you can destroy and re-create the social sharing plugins each time targeting them to this machine accessible version of that image.

**Snapshot Solution**
You can use a crawler tool that is capable of executing JavaScript to make snapshots of the different states of your application. You can then target the social sharing buttons to the snapshot of the current state.

This might require less back end work but may be challenging to keep up to date.